# AX2012-CRM 2011 Integratoin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

we are integrating CRM 2011 to AX2012. The problem is that our AX implementation has 8 companies and on CRM side we have different business unit. The connector will run and get all the data to each company and hence duplicating the information. How can we stop this.

I don't have good idea of AX but experienced with CRM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Above the mapping area you can specify the filters for your record :)

it was easy . enjoy Cheers :)